# How to exclude un-necessary DLLs from an MSI in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

I have a number of projects that are in solution, which reference DLLs from other Projects in the solution. However, some of DLLs, also reference other DLLs, such database connections, which are quite large and because of this I wish to exclude it from the build.

Is there away of doing this in the setup project? If so, how do you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I remember right, off the top of my head, you should be able to disable automatic dependencies. Furthermore, right clicking on the installer in the solution explorer should show you all the dependencies.  Simply delete the dependencies you don't want.

Of course, you run the risk of broken installer, but I think you'll figure that out.

J